# Find longest sequence of zeros in binary representation of an integer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, binary

1. Well in this question I have to find the longest sequence of zeros in the binary representation of an integer.
2. After a lot of hard work, I'm able to find the longest sequence of zeros with my logic which I changed many times.
3. I have one problem with my logic which is if I input an integer that has no gap in it has to give me an answer 0 which I tried to make by myself but I failed.
4. Right now if I input an integer that has no gap it gives me output infinity.
5. I want my answer to print 0 when the binary representation of an integer has no gap in it.

```js
var dn = prompt("Enter a number: ");
var bn = new Array();
var i = 0;
var binary = [];

while (dn != 0) {
  bn[i] = dn % 2;
  dn = Math.floor(dn / 2);
  i++;
}

for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
  binary.push(bn[j]);
}
console.log(binary.join(""));

var currentGap = 0;
var gaps = [];
var len = binary.length;

for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
  if (binary[k] == 0) {
    currentGap++;
    if (binary[k + 1] == 1) {
      gaps.push(currentGap);
      currentGap = 0;
    }
  }
}

console.log(Math.max(...gaps));
```

Comment: So just `if (gaps.length) console.log(Math.max(...gaps)) else console.log(0)`?

Answer (score 2):

You could add initialize gaps with 0, or add condition when gaps remains empty to print 0 else max of gaps.

```js
var dn = prompt("Enter a number: ");
var bn = new Array();
var i = 0;
var binary = [];

while (dn != 0) {
  bn[i] = dn % 2;
  dn = Math.floor(dn / 2);
  i++;
}

for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
  binary.push(bn[j]);
}
console.log(binary.join(""));

var currentGap = 0;
//var gaps = []
var gaps = [0];
var len = binary.length;

for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
  if (binary[k] == 0) {
    currentGap++;
    if (binary[k + 1] == 1) {
      gaps.push(currentGap);
      currentGap = 0;
    }
  }
}
//if (gaps.length === 0)
//  console.log(0)
//else
//  console.log(Math.max(...gaps));
console.log(Math.max(...gaps));
```

Answer (score 1):

just change `var gaps = [];`
to `var gaps = [0];`

You can also do that...

```js
let dn = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number: "))

if (isNaN(dn)) console.log('Not a Number!')
else
  {
  let
    dnStr = dn.toString(2)  // binary convertion
  , count = 0
  , zVal  = '0'
    ;
  while (dnStr.includes(zVal) ) 
    {
    count++
    zVal += '0'
    }

  console.log( `${dnStr}\n--> ${count}` )
  }
```

If you want to do your own binary convertion, prefert o use Javasscript binary opérators:

```js
let dn = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number: "))

if (isNaN(dn)) console.log('Not a Number!')
else
  {
  let gap   = [0]
  let Bin   = []
  let count = 0
  for (;;)
    {
    Bin.unshift(  dn & 1  )  // --> dn % 2
    if (dn & 1) 
      {
      gap.push(count)
      count = 0  
      }
    else count++

    dn >>>=1          // --> dn = Math.floor(dn / 2)
    if (!dn) break    // --> if (dn === 0 )
    }

  console.log(Bin.join(''))
  console.log(Math.max(...gap))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply print `0` if your gaps array has no length.

```js
var dn = prompt("Enter a number: ");
var bn = new Array();
var i = 0;
var binary = [];

while (dn != 0) {
  bn[i] = dn % 2;
  dn = Math.floor(dn / 2);
  i++;
}

for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
  binary.push(bn[j]);
}
console.log(binary.join(""));

var currentGap = 0;
var gaps = [];
var len = binary.length;

for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
  if (binary[k] == 0) {
    currentGap++;
    if (binary[k + 1] == 1) {
      gaps.push(currentGap);
      currentGap = 0;
    }
  }
}

console.log(gaps.length ? Math.max(...gaps) : 0); // <-- This
```

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if I'm misunderstanding your question, but would this satisfy your problem?

```js
const s = prompt("Enter a number:");
const longest = Math.max(...parseInt(s).toString(2).split('1').map(s=>s.length));

console.log(longest);
```

Comment: I don't think you understand it well. See the following example, please. For example, number 9 has binary representation 1001 and contains a binary gap of length 2. The number 529 has binary representation 1000010001 and contains two binary gaps: one of length 4 and one of length 3. The number 20 has binary representation 10100 and contains one binary gap of length 1. The number 15 has binary representation 1111 and has no binary gaps. The number 32 has binary representation 100000 and has no binary gaps.

Comment: @BrhaneGiday The question only asked to find the length of the longest sequence of zeros, and didn't specify they needed to be surrounded by ones. However, if that's what you're looking for, you could modify the line to ...`split('1').slice(1, -1).map(`...

Answer (score 1):

I had a go at this and this is what I came up with as a function:

```
function binaryGap(N){
    let binary = Math.abs(N).toString(2); // Convert to Binary string
    let binarySplit = binary.split("1"); // Split the string wherever there is "1"
    let tempBinaryArr = []; // create an empty array to store the element from Splice
    let max = 0; // Setting the max length to zero to compare with each element

    // Removing the zeros at the end
    if(binarySplit[binarySplit.length -1] == 0){
        tempBinaryArr = binarySplit.splice(binarySplit.length -1, 1);
    }

    //Looping through each element of binarySplit to compare with variable max
    for(let j=0; j < binarySplit.length; j++){
        if(max < binarySplit[j].length){
            max = binarySplit[j].length;
        }
    }

    return `Longest Sequence of Zeros: ${max}`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the task correctly, you can arrange the logic in something like this. In case if the input comes as a string you don't need the .toString() part

```js
function splitByZero(str) {
  const eachSubstr = str
    .toString()
    .split(1)
    .filter((e) => e); //to remove empty values in the new array
  let maxLength = 0;

  for (const substr of eachSubstr) {
    if (maxLength < substr.length) {
      maxLength = substr.length;
    }
  }
  console.log(maxLength);
}

splitByZero(111011100011);
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem well.  See the following description by example, please. For example, number 9 has binary representation 1001 and contains a binary gap of length 2. The number 529 has binary representation 1000010001 and contains two binary gaps: one of length 4 and one of length 3. The number 20 has binary representation 10100 and contains one binary gap of length 1. The number 15 has binary representation 1111 and has no binary gaps. The number 32 has binary representation 100000 and has no binary gaps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findLongestDistance(){
  findGap("1000100100001");
  findGap("1000100");
  findGap("000100");
  findGap("10000");
  findGap("000001");
  findGap("111111")
}

function findGap(n){
  var split = n.split(/1/g);
  var longestZeros = 0;
  if(split.length>2){
    for(var i in split){
      var len = split[i].length;
      if(len>longestZeros){
        longestZeros = len;
      }
    }
    console.log(longestZeros);
    return longestZeros;
  }
  console.log(0);
  return 0;
}
```